# WSO2 Identity Server SOAP API and clustering

Tags: session, wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

`RemoteUMClient` code sample indicates that WSO2 IS (Identity Server) might be using session management since an `authCookie` is being returned.

My question is how will this work in an clustered environment? Do WSO2 IS instances share the session information somehow?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but since all wso2 servers are using an embedded tomcat (that supports clustering out of the box) and thus are cluster-ready there should be a session replication among the servers.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Identity Server session replication doing in Axis2 level.

Clustering WSO2 products done using Axis2 clustering functionalities. So if the session needed to share across the cluster its needed to enable session replication in `axis2.xml` as follows.

Step 1: Open `axis2.xml` in `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml` and locate clustering section

Step 2: Enable clustering by, `<clustering class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesClusteringAgent" enable="true">`

Step 3: Enable session replication by, `<stateManager class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.state.DefaultStateManager" enable="true">`

Thanks!